# Zip Archive Progress has Incompatible block pointer types assigned

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm merely trying to run an app in simulator to see if assets and changes to a .json file were implemented correctly, however, when I attempt to run the app it fails and returns:

*Incompatible block pointer types assigning to 'ZipArchiveProgressUpdateBlock' (aka 'void (^)(int, int, unsigned long)') from 'void (^)(int, int, int)'*

The whole block is below and the issue references the specific line:

*zip.progressBlock = ^ (int percentage, int filesProcessed, int numFiles)*

```
ZipArchive* zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[zip UnzipOpenFile:pathToZipFile];
zip.delegate = self;
zip.progressBlock = ^ (int percentage, int filesProcessed, int numFiles){
[self showProgress:PackageDownloadStateUnzipping progress:(float)percentage/100.0f];
};
BOOL success = [zip UnzipFileTo:unzippedDestination overWrite:YES];

if ( !success ){
    self.state = PackageDownloadStateUnzipError;
}else{
    self.state = PackageDownloadStateUnzipped;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error. It tells you the problem. The block expects three parameters with type of `int`, `int`, and `unsigned long`. But your block has three `int` parameters.

Simply change the 3rd parameter's type from `int` to `unsigned long`.

```
zip.progressBlock = ^ (int percentage, int filesProcessed, unsigned long numFiles){
    [self showProgress:PackageDownloadStateUnzipping progress:(float)percentage/100.0f];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the block you assign takes (int,int,int) but the ZipArchive expects you to pass one that takes (int,int,unsigned long) -- at least, that's what the error message says.

I'm surprised that its getting to running - are you sure it isn't failing at compile time?